# My rewrite rule give me a 500. What is wrong?

Tags: xml, web-config

When I add a new rule to Web.config I get a HTTP 500 error. I'm on Azure.

The following give an **error** message:

```
<rule name="Rewrite ticket and segment" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{1,5})\/?" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/api/getTicket.php?ticketId={R:1}&segment={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

but this one it **working**:

```
<rule name="Rewrite ticket" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4})\/?" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/api/getTicket.php?ticketId={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reason is, you have invalid `XML`. Since `web.config` is `XML` based `&` is not that what you think.

Change the `&` to `&amp;` and it will work.

```
<rule name="Rewrite ticket and segment" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{1,5})\/?" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/api/getTicket.php?ticketId={R:1}&amp;segment={R:2}" />
</rule>
```